# Handling option groups in Access form- runtime error 2427

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an option group on a form. I want the form to process code based on which button is selected. The snippet I have for now is:

```
If Me.Option18.Value = True Then
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Logbook Query all available"
End If
```

Option 18 is the radio button on the form.
On the If line, I get 'run time error 2427: You entered an expression that has no value'

I tried different uses of me.option 18, and get the same error. I also tried replacing 'true' with 1, same result.

Is there a better way to execute code based on an option group selection. or is this simply a syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the *group* that hosts the options, and the options normally are assigned values like 1, 2, and 3:

```
If Me.OptionGroup.Value = 2 Then
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Logbook Query all available"
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, this was my first try with an option group.